# ParseQueryAdapter for nested objects not working

Tags: android, parse-platform

For my Android app, I have subclassed ParseObject to create **Food**, **Pref** classes and **CustomUser class which extends ParseUser** and created a relation "lovers" between 'Food' and 'Users'.

> Inside a CustomUser object, I have stored an Pref object using
>   createWithoutData method in key "pref".CustomUser and its
>   respective Pref object have one-to-one mapping

So when I want to display all lovers of a particular food in a listview using ParseQueryAdapter,

```
ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(getActivity(),
    new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
        public ParseQuery<ParseObject> create() {
               ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = food.getRelation("lovers").getQuery();
               query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("pref");                                      
               return query;
        }
    });
```

> adapter.setTextKey(Pref.COLUMN_PROFILE_NAME); 
>   adapter.setImageKey(Pref.COLUMN_PROFILE_PIC_THUMB);

fyi,  COLUMN_PROFILE_NAME = "profileName", COLUMN_PROFILE_PIC_THUMB = "profileThumb"

Now the problem is that "pref" is only a reference to the actual object. So when the listView tries to get text and image, it says *"ParseObject has no data for this key.  Call fetchIfNeeded() to get the data"*

**My objective is to pass a query to ParseQueryAdapter that will fetch all pref objects nested inside CustomUsers having 'lovers' relation with that particular food.**

The parse docs say that 'include' method does not work on relations.

Please help, I have been struggling on this for long now.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve a relation, I don't believe you can use a query. In your case you would use

```
ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = user.getRelation("lovers");
```

[See this documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-pointers)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Below, an example showing off the level of configuration available with this class:

```
// Instantiate a QueryFactory to define the ParseQuery to be used for fetching items in this
 // Adapter.
 ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory =
     new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
       public ParseQuery create() {
         ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Customer");
         //query.whereEqualTo("activated", true);
         //query.orderByDescending("moneySpent");
     query.include("your key");

         return query;
       }
     };

 // Pass the factory into the ParseQueryAdapter's constructor.
 ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, factory);
 adapter.setTextKey("name");

 // Perhaps set a callback to be fired upon successful loading of a new set of ParseObjects.
 adapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>() {
   public void onLoading() {
     // Trigger any "loading" UI
   }

   public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
     // Execute any post-loading logic, hide "loading" UI
   }
 });

 // Attach it to your ListView, as in the example above
 ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```